# Can Meteor handle nested views?

Tags: meteor

I'm learning meteor, and finding all kinds of difficulties dealing with nested subviews. Since the application I want to write is full of them... that looks like a difficulty.  I found this on github, as a readme for a Meteor project to try and deal with this problem.
"I've been playing around with Meteor for a couple weeks. The ease of setup and the powerful reactivity makes this something I want to stick with. I was however frustrated by the difficulty of programmatically configuring, instantiating, destroying and nesting subviews."

Is this an issue that can be handled in Meteor (without adding a lot of complicated work arounds) or should I look for a different platform ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple yield in Meteor.js application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526502/multiple-yield-in-meteor-js-application)

Answer (score 0):

I love nesting templates.  I get reliable results.  I now program off a library of both templates and helper functions (usually for form elements) that compose html for me.  HTML is a byproduct, and the files we call .html are really a javascript DSL.

There are many S.O. issues raised about insertions into sorted lists giving people problems.  I haven't had time to look.

My rule of thumb:  Meteor is (well) designed from the beginning to do this easily and reliably.

So far the harder thing to solve was when I added an accordion from foundation, and a refresh of the document led to its initial state (being all closed, or one open).  I had to put code in that saved the current section, and code to re-assert that in the rendered callback for the template that used it.

Why not write a prototype of the nesting with just a field or two in places, and find what bothers you?

Here is a sample chain.  You see all the nested templates.  This template itself is running within multiple.

First template:  called 'layout', suggested by iron router.  Has basic page and menu.  Main body is a yield, set by router.  On a sample page, a route calls template 'availability'

```
<template name='availability'>
  {{#each myAgents}}
  <form class="custom" id="Agent_{{_id}}" action="">
    <div id='availability' class="section-container accordion" data-section="accordion">
      <section id="services">
        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Your Info
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>services}}
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="skills">
        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Skills
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>skills}}
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="sureties">
        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Sureties
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>sureties}}
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="time">

        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Time Available
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>time}}
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="schedule1">

        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Schedule 1
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>schedule}}
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="schedule2">

        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Schedule 2
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>schedule}}
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="distance">

        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">
          Distance
        </a></p>

        <div class="content" data-section-content>
          {{>distance}}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </form>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

sample further nest:

```
<template name='services'>
  {{label_text fname='name' title='Agent Name' placeholder='Formal Name' collection='agent'  passthrough='autofocus=autofocus ' }}
  {{label_text fname='agentInCharge' title='Agent In Charge' placeholder='Owner' collection='agent'   }}
  {{label_text fname='phone' title='Phone Number(s)' placeholder='Include Area  Code'collection='agent'   }}
  {{>gps }}

  <h4>Not shared:</h4>
  {{label_text fname='email' title='Email:' placeholder='you remain anonymous' collection='agent' }}

</template>
```

and label_text is a helper, learned from the https://github.com/mcrider/azimuth project:

```
generateField = (options) ->
  options.hash.uniqueId = options.hash.fieldName + "_" + Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)  if options.hash.template is "wysiwyg"
  options.hash.id = options.hash.id or @_id
  options.hash.value = options.hash.value or this[options.hash.fname]

  # allow for simple params as default
  options.hash.title = options.hash.title or options.hash.fname
  options.hash.template = options.hash.template or "label_text"
  options.hash.placeholder = options.hash.placeholder or options.hash.title

  # compatible with old
  options.hash.fieldName = options.hash.fieldname or options.hash.fname
  options.hash.label = options.hash.label or options.hash.title

  # FIXME: Return error if type not valid template
  new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[options.hash.template](options.hash))



Handlebars.registerHelper "label_text", (options) ->
  options.hash.collection = options.hash.collection or 'generic'  
  generateField.call this, options
```

Comment: I am writing a form. I've dealt with nesting a template to lay out a select for the main form.

Comment: I am writing an application right now. My problem is that I cannot find any information on nested templates... most of the meteor examples are of fairly flat forms... there is a little here and there but for a beginner its fairly hard to have to piece everything together for yourself.

Comment: I posted an example.  Is there a specific problem? Is this about the #with hiding the previous context, from your other question?

Comment: Jim, thanks, your comments and your encouragement helped along..turns out the nested #with problem was not really a problem when i went back to my code i got it working... i also found all the libraries on atmosphere.. which will probably be a good place to learn more

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to Meteor, but I found out really soon that I wanted nested views (aka dynamic includes or sub-templates). I'm not sure whether this is what you mean, but here is my solution.

I created the following handlebars helper, that can be used to create sub-templates:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('subTemplate', function(container, property, context, options) {
    if (container && container.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        var subTemplate = container[property];
        if (typeof subTemplate === 'function') {
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(subTemplate(context || this));
        }
        else if (typeof subTemplate === 'string') {
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[subTemplate](context || this));
        }
    }
});
```

It can be used inside something I call a generic template. For example to create a list:

```
<template name="item_list">
    <ul class="items-list">
        {{#each items}}
            <li class="listview-item">
                {{subTemplate .. 'listItem' this}}
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Now invoking this generic template requires that a 'listItem' property is present within its context. This can be either a string with the name of the sub-template, or the inline definition of a sub-template. The example below shows both options:

```
<template name="my_list">
    {{! First option, referring to the sub-template by name:}}
    <div>
        {{#with listData listItem="my_list_item"}}
            {{> item_list}}
        {{/with}}
    </div>

    {{! Second option, inlining the sub-template:}}
    <div>
        {{#with listData}}
            {{#assignPartial 'listItem'}}
                <span>{{name}}</span>
            {{/assignPartial}}
            {{> item_list}}
        {{/with}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="my_list_item">
    <span>{{name}}</span>
</template>

Template.my_list.listData = function() {
    return {
        items: collections.people.find()
    };
};
```

The second option requires an extra handlebars helper.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('assignPartial', function(prop, options) {
    this[prop] = options.fn;
    return '';
});
```

I made more of these kinds of useful helpers, at some point I will probably share them on GitHub.