# Multiple yield in Meteor.js application template

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have one general {{>yield}} for iron-router in a layout file which renders my pages, which are templates.

In one of my pages, I have a side menu and according to the selection in this menu, I want to load different templates related to this page in this page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The reference for the accepted answer is https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#layouts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have done a similar thing using iron-router's `layout template` option. Say I want to create a home view with multiple views/templates inside of this home view that will change. First I would declare my route:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('home', {
  path: '/',
  template: 'myHomeTemplate',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'myAsideTemplate': {to: 'aside'},
    'myFooter': {to: 'footer'}
    }
  });
});
```

Where the html for the layout template would look like:

```
 <template name="layout">
   <aside>
     {{> yield region='aside'}}
   </aside>

  <div>
    {{> yield}}
  </div>

  <footer>
    {{> yield region='footer'}}
  </footer>
</template>
```

So that the templates specified in the yields `aside` and `footer` get rendered in the specified spot. For your case you can specify a `sidemenu` yield.

No that you have the basic layout and idea you can define another route. Say we call it `differentHome`.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('differentHome', {
  path: '/differentHome',
  template: 'myHomeTemplate',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'myDifferentAsideTemplate': {to: 'aside'},
    'myDifferentFooter': {to: 'footer'}
    }
  });
});
```

Notice on this route declaration I am changing the yield templates, but I am not changing the basic template that will be rendered in the main yield. Now on an event you can re-route which will change the two different yields templates:

```
Router.go("differentHome");
```

Or you can use html to route, say with a link.

EDIT (Haphazard Solution):

Use Session Variable To Dictate Side Menu choice.

```
HTML:
<template name="main">
  ......
   <div class="sideMenu">   
     {{#if sideMenu1}}
        {{> side1Template}}
     {{/if}}

     {{#if sideMenu2}}
        {{> side2Template}}
     {{/if}}
   </div>
 </template>

JS:
Template.main.helpers({
    sideMenu1 : function () {
         return Session.equals("sideMenuChoice", "sideMenu1")  
    },
    sideMenu2 : function () {
         return Session.equals("sideMenuChoice", "sideMenu2")  
    }
 });
```

Now on an event set the Session to what ever sideMenuChoice.

Comment: How can I change yieldTemplates values by clicking list item instead of assigning them in router.

Comment: You could use a haphazard implementation with Session variables that dictate the Side Menu even outside of Iron-router routes. It wouldn't be a very tidy solution but you could make it work. See EDIT above.

Comment: Note that you can define `yield`s in your template that you leave unused for some routes, which can come is super handy.