# MeteorJS template placeholder

Tags: javascript, meteor, template-engine

Iam getting started with MeteorJS/Iron Router/Blaze and I'm trying to figure out how to set placeholder for template.

I have a menu and a footer, which will change only partialy, but between them is the main content which should be based on current route. Point is that i need some sort of pointer, like in angular "ng-view".

Eg.

```
<menu></menu>
{{some sort of placeholder}}
<footer></footer>
```

and in router:

```
Router.route('/', function () {

//render some template exactly into placeholder, dont append it to the bottom

});
```

Maybe there is something wrong with my understanding of meteorjs templating, I just base my way of solving this problem on angular templating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I got your question but here is an answer:

You can do that with the `{{> yield}}` tag. It will define an **dynamic area which will show the view corresponding to the current route**.

You can also "design" a layout for your entire app, like you did, for example `layout.html` :

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
  <header class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'home'}}">My app</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And tell Iron-Router that your app has to fit this layout :

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

    // Then just define your routes

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {path: '/'});
});
```

You may notice I used `{{pathFor 'home'}}` in the layout. Iron Router let you use route "names" so it won't do anything if you change the URL.

I suggest you read an awesome book called [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/) !

Comment: Thats it, I wasnt thinking about "composing" final view of templates but just about injecting template, and that was my mistake. I just found more complex [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526502/multiple-yield-in-meteor-js-application-template), which might fit my need, but yours works too :)